# If statement run in first line

Tags: excel, vba

Hi everyone i have a problem and i try my best to solve it but i cant
I have a VBA code to check if 2 values is equal each others and run some lines but the code run in first line and skip the others.

I tried `strcomp` but it gave same problem.

This is the first code to get data from listbox1 into textboxs

```
Dim userin As Long
userin = Me.ListBox1.ListIndex
Me.TextBox6 = Me.ListBox1.List(userin, 0)
Me.TextBox1 = Me.ListBox1.List(userin, 1)
Me.TextBox2 = Me.ListBox1.List(userin, 2)
Me.ComboBox1 = Me.ListBox1.List(userin, 3)
Me.ComboBox2 = Me.ListBox1.List(userin, 4)
Me.TextBox3 = Me.ListBox1.List(userin, 5)
Me.TextBox4 = Me.ListBox1.List(userin, 6)
Me.ComboBox3 = Me.ListBox1.List(userin, 7) 
end sub
```

And this code to try to compare 2 values to find the row to let the user to edit data

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
    Dim LastRow As Long 
    Dim NewRow As Long 
    LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    For NewRow = 3 To LastRow 
        If Sheet1.Cells(NewRow, 1) = CInt(Me.TextBox6) Then 
            Sheet1.Cells(NewRow, 2) = Me.TextBox1 
            Sheet1.Cells(NewRow, 3) = Me.TextBox2 
        End If 
    Next NewRow 
End Sub
```

the code only run the first line

Comment: Please create a [reprex].

Comment: Do you seriously believe that we can guess your code ?

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NewRow As Long
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For NewRow = 3 To LastRow
        If Sheet1.Cells(NewRow, 1) = CInt(Me.TextBox6) Then
           Sheet1.Cells(NewRow, 2) = Me.TextBox1
           Sheet1.Cells(NewRow, 3) = Me.TextBox2
           End If
       Next NewRow
       
        
    
End Sub

This is my code

Comment: `Debug.Print LastRow ` to check its value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My code was to take data form listbox 1 and put it in textbox and comper between 2 value text6 and cells(1,1) which came from listbox for get the rownumber to let the user to edit

Comment: Most likely, the data in the textbox and in the cell a not identically, but noone has your data so it is impossible to tell exactly what is going in. You should learn to use the VBA debugger, execute the code step by step and check where the code fails and what the content of the variables and cells are.

Comment: Funthomas i try to track the code step by step and when if is true the code execute only one line and jump to next sub

Comment: https://k.top4top.io/p_279071xyp0.jpeg
This pic show my issue the code skip second line of if and got to next sub